# Is 'dégueulasse' a swear word?

Tags: expressions, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

Is 'dégueulasse' a swear word or gros mot? Or is it appropriate to use day to day?

Comment: It's like eating a meal and saying to the cook "This is horrible!". There's a place for that word, but it is so strong that it can be insulting for the person hearing it. When I was a teen, we used to say "Dégueu"

Comment: @the_lotus Which also holds true for the English counterpart "disgusting", with a similar reference to puking.

Comment: I wonder how it stacks up against "[vomitrocious](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2JuAvzMGwSw)". :D

Comment: The answers are nice but none point out that the word can be applied to people, mainly to rail against their lack of personal hygiene. There's even a [French BD titled "Gros Dégueulasse"](http://www.glenatbd.com/bd/gros-degueulasse-9782723484572.htm) (NSFW) whose protagonist embodies that.

Comment: @Aaron - yeap. Can you write a full answer with that? It would nicely complement the answers we already have.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is not really a swear word, but I would tell my kids not to say that. It is not a "nice" word, although not extremely rude either. Let's say it is below average, polite conversation, but not very offensive either. You would most probably not write it. You can use it between friends, or in family (not counting the kids). The nuance is more one of disgust than anything else.

For example, if someone did something really bad to somebody else at work, you could react with *c'est vraiment dégueulasse*, *c'est vraiment dégueu* (also commonly used) to show your complete disgust and your contempt for the offender. *Disguting* with the proper tone in English is quite close, although the French *dégueulasse* is less advisable (*disgusting* and *dégoûtant* (see below) share a common root (but I did not verify)).

An even less advisable word would be *gerbax* ("*puke inducing*"?), and this is definitely reaching into slang. Going in the other direction, an alternative could be: *dégoûtant*, and here we have crossed into more polite territory, polite enough for any conversation. *Répugnant* works too. As do *révoltant* and *écoeurant*. These last three are quite-middle-of-the-road, with slightly different nuances each time. *Sale* and *horrible* would be possible, but too weak and tame. *Immonde* is possible. So is *infâme*, which is now quite formal.

Comment: ¿¿ **Gerbax** ??

Comment: I don't know gerbax either, but the rest of the answer is perfect

Comment: *Gerbax* makes me think of *gerbatoire* (which might not be in the dictionary either, but is more common IME).

Comment: I did show this word to my kids, but yes, they did tend to go overboard with it, since the matter it describes is, well, disgusting –and therefore very amusing to kids–, so I had to limit its use at some point, especially ostentatious use at meal time. Maybe one shouldn’t use it in some conversations, but then people should also not venture into the territory of doing disgusting things or talking about them, lest they trigger someone to throw the term at them as a mean to straighten them out.

Comment: @StephenKitt  Yes, I finally found a few occurrences of *gerbax* with that meaning. I didn't know that word.

Comment: Incidentally, *dégueulasse* and *marrant* were the two words I heard most often when I visited Paris. They seemed to be the standard judgements for situations typically arising in tourist season. :p

Comment: Yes _gerbax_ is from _gerber_, bad slang for _to puke_.

Comment: @jlliagre - did you find other meanings for _gerbax_?

Comment: No I didn't. That's precisely what you wrote. Thanks for teaching new vocabulary ;-)

Comment: @jlliagre - y-a-t'il d'autres mots d'un registre plus bas que _dégueulasse_, mais moins rare que _gerbax_?

Comment: Pas qui me viennent à l'esprit, non. À propos, *disgusting* et *dégoûtant* sont bien sûr apparentés; le *probably* n'est pas nécessaire.

Comment: Bon, je l'enlève. Je me méfie - il y a parfois de faux amis, et je n'ai pas vraiment vérifié. Si je n'ai pas fait de recherche, je me retranche facilement derrière un _probably_.

Comment: Je valide "gerbax" et j'ajoute que "dégueu" passe assez bien avec des enfants.

Answer (score 13):

I would say that *"dégueulasse"* is not a swear word, but it is offensive, although it is commonly used in casual situations. It litterally comes from *"dégueuler"* which is the offensive word for *"puke"*.

French has this concept of *"gros mot"* which covers vocabulary of a certain level that typically includes swearing, vulgarities, and rude or offensive words. *"Dégueulasse"* is not a swearing word but it is vulgar, so I would definitely label it as *"gros mot"*. Like Frank said, kids would probably be reprimanded for using it.

Many words that end with the suffix "-asse" are pejorative at various levels: *rêvasse* (familiar), *vinasse* (slang for bad wine), *tignasse*, *pétasse*, *pouffiasse* (down right insulting), etc.

Comment: Actually in some of those words `-asse` just indicates a female version of the noun, which is the most common use of that suffix.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Turning a noun into feminine is definitely not the common use of that suffix. See [-asse](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-asse).

Comment: The dictionary indicates that in both words, _"-asse"_ is indeed a pejorative suffix. See: http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/petasse and http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/poufiasse

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't say this is a particularly offensive word, rather I consider it familiar language. It would certainly sound strange in an official speech, but I have heard this word in daily use and never noticed people being frowned upon for using it. Especially, [*pas dégueulasse*](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/d%C3%A9gueulasse) is being used, meaning *not bad at all*.

Sure, the word does bear a negative connotation and can be used as offensive, especially if reinforced by constructs like *gros dégueulasse* or *espèce de dégueu*. But this is true of many words which are nevertheless appropriate in unofficial speech.